# Delete 2 cookies with the same key and value

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies, .net-core

*I know there are several questions regarding deleting a cookie here. I'm asking why I can't **delete 2 cookies with the same key and value**.

- The goal:

I'm working on a web application that has tons of legacy code, and in some cases, clients receive 2 cookies with the same key, value but the domain is different: one is explicit and the other is not (with and without dot notation aka `.domain.com`, `domain.com`). I need to delete both of those cookies.

- The problem:

**Only one of the cookies is being deleted.** The cookie is set from an ASP.NET application and the (.net core 2.1) API re-uses it. The API is a subdomain of the ASP.NET application, and the UI part is another subdomain.

- What eventually worked for me, is deleting all of the cookies:

```
   

    private void DeleteCookiesOnUnauthorizedResponse(HttpContext context)
            {
                var domain = new Uri(SOME_ENV_VARIABLE).Host;
    
                var options = GenerateExpiredCookieOptions(domain);
                var optionsWithDot = GenerateExpiredCookieOptions('.' + domain);
    
                var cookieList = context.Request.Cookies.ToList();
    
                foreach (var cookie in cookieList)
                {
                    context.Response.Cookies.Delete(cookie.Key, options);
                    context.Response.Cookies.Delete(cookie.Key, optionsWithDot);
                }
            }
```

```
     private CookieOptions GenerateExpiredCookieOptions(string domain)
            {
                return new CookieOptions
                {
                    Domain = domain,
                    Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-2),
                    IsEssential = true,
                    HttpOnly = true,
                    Secure = true,
                    Path = "/",
                    SameSite = SameSiteMode.Lax,
                };
            }
```

- What didn't work:

  The old fashion way of deleting a cookie

`context.Response.Cookies.Append(someKey, string.Empty, optionsWithExpiredDate);`

`context.Response.Cookies.Delete(someKey);`

Using a loop to delete only what I need didn't work either:

```
    foreach (var cookie in cookieList)
    {
          if(cookie.key == "myKey"){
                    context.Response.Cookies.Delete(cookie.Key, options);
                    context.Response.Cookies.Delete(cookie.Key, optionsWithDot);
           }
    }
```

Both of the cookies were sent to the browser as seen in the network tab, but only one of them got deleted.

[image]

- The question:

  Why? I don't want to delete all of the cookies, just those 2, but one of them appears to be indestructible.

Comment: Why can you add two same key cookies? the value will be covered when thier key is  same.

Comment: You can have 2 cookies with the same key and value. They are not being covered or overwritten. And the browser sends them both in the requests. The reason that I have 2 cookies is that part of the code is quite old, and sometimes clients get 2 cookies, one with a dot notation, the other without. This is not the part I'm trying to fix now though.